# How do I remotely host a C# Web Service with a custom URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, web-services

I recently made a Restful C# web service. It is currently hosted on my PC's localhost. How would I remotely and publicly host this API so that anyone can access it from anywhere, with a URL that i choose? (If there are any free options that would be great, but i understand if not) I have done a good amount of digging but haven't found a suitable solution. Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not on-topic, you will only get comments, but you need a web host, of which there are many. Microsoft Azure has free hosting but you can only pick your subdomain on the free tier, not the full URL.

Comment: "I have done a good amount of digging but haven't found a suitable solution" you have not tried hard enough

Comment: Crowcoder, thanks for the help! Steve, thanks for the useless derogatory comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to do that (some of them are free, and some of them not).

Good and simple options is Azure Web App Service, and you can find documentation and "how to do" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet-framework)

About attach custom URL (custom domain name) you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-custom-domain-name-migrate)